# How to create supported device white list from Google Play Store Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-market-filtering

I have an Android Application published on the Google Play Store. I want my application to be displayable just a few specific devices on the play store for users. Actually, I can exclude devices one by one but if a new device is added to Google Play Store I don't want to be displayable my application for this new device. Is there any way to create a supported device white list from the device catalogue on the Google Play Store console?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something that the Play Console supports.

Comment: Thanks, @Pierre but I need to do this limitation. Is there any way to achieve this limitation by doing any other modification from Play Store Console or  Android Source code? Maybe, I could exclude all the devices defaulty from the market then just include devices that I want to displayable on. In this way, If a new device is added to the Google Play Store, my application will be excluded defaulty.

Comment: You can exclude devices based on SoC, Android versions, SafetyNet profile, etc. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455

Comment: I could decrease included devices count highly by using the document you shared. But still have a lot of supported devices except my devices which I want to be displayable on the market. I think I could exclude manually the other devices. Thanks for your help @Pierre